# cookie name is not being set when using res.setheader() in expressjs value is getting set

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to set the value of a request parameter in my cookies. the value is getting set in the browser but the name is not getting set

here is request in which I am setting the cookie

```
router.post('/getsearchvalue',(req,res,next)=>{
   var proteinname =req.body.proteinname;
   console.log(proteinname)
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', proname = req.body.proteinname )
    console.log("inside post")
    res.render('searchresult')
})
```

when I check the application tab in debuggers mode in google chrome I can see the name column as blank but the value column has the desired value

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error, you actually want to set a string:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `proname=${req.body.proteinname}`)
```

Comment: many thanks to you it's working. was stuck with this for the last 3 hours.  it would be of more help if you can let me know where I can learn more about the format of it

Comment: @K.M.J - Cookies described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

Comment: And [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is the syntax for template literals in ES6.